# How to fix the error "Windows SDK version 8.1" was not found?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I recently updated visual studio 2015 and now, when i try to build *any* project it always fails and i get the error

> Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>       Error MSB8036 The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the
>   project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting
>   "Retarget solution".  Proj    D:\Program Files (x86)\visual studio
>   2017\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v141\Toolset.targets   34

I retargeted the solution as it said, and the problem persisted, even though the retargetting was completed.I decided to install visual studio 2017 because of this, and, lo and behold, it did the exact same thing.I'm also using windows 7.

What is the problem and how can i fix it?

Comment: Rerun the install and verify that the specific SDK is selected. It might not be by default. If it *is* already selected, try the Repair option instead.

Comment: i tried the repair and it sadly didnt work.Also, in the install, i dont have any options for a sdk

Answer (score 158, accepted):

I faced this problem too. Re-ran the **Visual Studio 2017 Installer**, go to **'Individual Components'** and select `Windows 8.1 SDK`. Go back to to the project > Right click and Re-target to match the SDK required as shown below:[image]

Comment: Right. You have to install 8.1 SDK before you can change it.

Comment: Sdk8.1 is included inside vs2017. I selected it from the vs2017 installer but i am still getting the same error. Retargeting is done without errors. What seèms to be wrong here?

Comment: Based on your screenshot there, you have a version of the Windows 10 SDK already installed.  This SDK supports Windows 7 SP1 and later, so unless you have a specific need for the 8.1 SDK, you should probably just stick with what you have.

Answer (score 54):

I installed the 8.1 SDK's version:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

It used 1GB (a little more) in the installation.

---

**Update October, 9 (2020).** There's a https error: the sdksetup link is https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=323507

"Save link as" should help.

Comment: this is the correct answer for VS  2019 users as Windows 8.1 SDK doest no longer exist in vs installer

Comment: @AAEM weirdly didn't download on Chome for me, but worked in Firefox

Comment: There's a https error. The url for the sdksetup is https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=323507

Comment: Kinda stunning how useless VS was/is re. resolving this

Answer (score 10):

Another way (worked for 2015) is open "Install/remove programs" (Apps & features), find Visual Studio, select Modify. In opened window, press Modify, check

- `Languages -> Visual C++ -> Common tools for Visual C++`
- `Windows and web development -> Tools for universal windows apps -> Tools (1.4.1)
  and Windows 10 SDK ([version])`
- `Windows and web development -> Tools for universal windows apps -> Windows 10 SDK ([version])`

and install. Then right click on solution -> Re-target and it will compile

Answer (score 5):

I had win10 SDK and I only had to do retarget and then I stopped getting this error. The idea was that the project needs to upgrade its target Windows SDK.

Answer (score 5):

I realize this post is a few years old, but I just wanted to extend this to anyone still struggling through this issue.

The company I work for still uses VS2015 so in turn I still use VS2015. I recently started working on a RPC application using C++ and found the need to download the Win32 Templates. Like many others I was having this "SDK 8.1 was not found" issue. i took the following corrective actions with no luck.

- I found the SDK through Micrsoft at the following link 
  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/ as referenced 
  above and downloaded it.
- I located my VS2015 install in Apps & Features and ran the repair.
- I completely uninstalled my VS2015 and reinstalled it.
- I attempted to manually point my console app "Executable" and "Include" directories to the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\8.1 and C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools.

None of the attempts above corrected the issue for me...

I then found this article on social MSDN https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5287c51b-46d0-4a79-baad-ddde36af4885/visual-studio-cant-find-windows-81-sdk-when-trying-to-build-vs2015?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Finally what resolved the issue for me was:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling VS2015.
- Locating my installed "Windows Software Development Kit for Windows 8.1" and running the repair.
- Checked my "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\8.1" to verify the "DesignTime" folder was in fact there.
- Opened VS created a Win32 Console application and comiled with no errors or issues

I hope this saves anyone else from almost 3 full days of frustration and loss of productivity.

Comment: vs2015 build tools installer is no longer available due to sha-1 deprecation.

Answer (score 2):

For me in the Project Properties Settings General->Target Platform -> Change Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 solved the issue

Comment: For me in Visual Studio 2019, I had to right-click each project, open the properties for each one.  

Under "Configuration Properties" » "General" » "Platform Toolset"

I was able to change the target version.

Answer (score 1):

- Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version
  in the project property pages

  or
- by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution"

If you do visual studio guide, you will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Grep the folder tree's `*.vcxproj` files. Replace `<WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>8.1</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>` with `<WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>` or whatever SDK version you get when you update one of the projects.

Comment: If you are going to downvote at least say why - this worked on my machine.

Comment: Interesting option. Another route that I personally prefer is you can override these parameters at build time. Ex: msbuild xx.csproj/xx.sln /t:build /p:WindowsTargetPlatformVersion=xx;WindowsTargetPlatformMinVersion=xx (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58489661/146698)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue while trying to build an npm project. It was failing to install a node-sass package and this was the error it was printing. I solved it by setting my npm proxy correctly so that it could reach the npm repo

Comment: So that you...?

Comment: haha, not sure what happened there ;)

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM:  I ONLY get this compile-time "Windows SDK version 8.1 not found" error ( and a few other very-hard-to-resolve-nuisance errors -- cannot list them all ) when I export a project from an old version of MS Visual Studio (VS) to the new MS VS (2017), using the new MS VS export/"One-way Upgrade" feature.

SOLUTION:  I have since learned to not use this export/upgrade feature and instead just create the new project from scratch -- using all my old source files, of course.  Only my project settings have to be rebuilt, to be clear.

This is a bit of a pain, and a shame the export/upgrade feature won't work properly like it used to, but this is is actually easier and faster in the long run.  MUCH better than working through a list of spurious errors that really should not have arisen in the first place.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio, and go to File -> New -> Project -> Visual C++, it will allow you install Windows 8.1 SDK with the first option.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the sdksetup using

```
curl -L https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=323507 --output sdksetup.exe
```

It gives the following `/help` output

[image: The help of the sdksetup]

So it appears installing it with `.\sdksetup /features + /q` should fix this

Answer (score 0):

In my project the error was because of a reference to a not retargeted project. This reference could be invisible in the solution tree. So you can remove it by editing xml source of the project file.

1. open .vcxproj file in the editor as plain text
2. find a section `<ProjectReference Include=` which points to any .vcxproj project file that is not needed in your project and remove it.