# How can I specify "Target Platform Version" and "Target Platform Min. Version" when compiling with MSBuild, VS 2019, Platform Toolset v142

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2019, c++-winrt

Project files have these settings in a PropertyGroup named Globals:

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
  ...
  <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
  <WindowsTargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.14393.0</WindowsTargetPlatformMinVersion>
  ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

I wasn't able to find any documentation about how to set these on the command line with MSBuild.

Comment: Doesn't the standard commandline functionality work for these? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019#global-properties

Comment: In case you're not familiar with msbuild, the format of the commands see: `msbuild xx.csproj/xx.sln /t:build /p:WindowsTargetPlatformVersion=xx;WindowsTargetPlatformMinVersion=xx`... More details please refer to the document in **stijn**'s comment.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I wasn't aware I could provide the values from the project file simply "as is" using the /p argument. Please add your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the simple `/p` argument can do the trick. Using command like:

`msbuild xx.csproj/xx.sln /t:build /p:WindowsTargetPlatformVersion=xx;WindowsTargetPlatformMinVersion=xx` (should be in one line) can specify the target version in runtime.

**Note**: To run commands above, you should make sure the windows sdk version you wanna specify is installed in your machine.