# Installing the Windows SDK 8.1 version in Azure Pipelines

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-2019

I want to upgrade my Azure Pipeline vmImage to 'windows-2019' in order to compile my project with Visual Studio 2019.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  appxPackageDir: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\\'

steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build the project'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(buildPlatform)" /p:AppxPackageDir="$(appxPackageDir)" /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload'
- task: VSTest@2
```

However, the Windows SDK 8.1 [seems not to be included](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/windows-sdk-81-gone-from-vs2019/517851) in this image. When I try to compile my C++ project:

> ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v150\Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsSDK.targets(46,5):
> Error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the
> required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the
> project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting
> "Retarget solution".

How to install it in this image?

**Related:**

[How to fix the error "Windows SDK version 8.1" was not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704734/how-to-fix-the-error-windows-sdk-version-8-1-was-not-found)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you specifically need the 8.1 SDK? Is there anything in the Windows 8.1 SDK that's not included in the Windows 10 SDK?

Comment: @IInspectable it's legacy code running in industrial environment and some of the computers running it are still WinXp.

Comment: Targeting Windows XP doesn't require you to use the Windows 8.1 SDK, though. Unless there are some changes I am not aware of, you can build applications for Windows XP using the Windows 10 SDK.

Comment: @IInspectable It might be. We had some trouble keeping WinXP compatible with this a while ago, so I chose to use the same SDK as before. But it worth giving it a try, thanks!

Comment: The Windows API (and its SDK), to my knowledge, is fully ABI compatible, all the way back, since the beginning of time. What changed is the platform toolset (i.e. the compiler and its support libraries). You'll have to use a Windows XP compatible platform toolset, but (again, to my knowledge) there is no such restriction on the SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used choco in order to get the Windows 8.1 SDK:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Install the win 8.1 SDK'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      choco install windows-sdk-8.1
```